# Cannot install Flexisip (Linphone SIP server) on Centos 6.8

Tags: centos, linphone, sip-server, hiredis

I am building Voice Call feature for Android app by using Linphone.

On server (CentOS 6.8), I install Flexisip by tutorial on Homepage of Linphone wiki (https://wiki.linphone.org/wiki/index.php/Flexisip:installation).

However in step 1, I cannot install "EPEL repository" for hiredis-devel package because this link is not found: http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/epel/7/x86_64/repoview/epel-release.html. If I ignore step 1, then when install Flexisip, it require hiredis-devel with version 0.11 or higher.

So I have some questions:

1. Can I install Flexisip on CentOS 6.8 ? or Flexisip require CentOS 7 and more recent ?
2. If I can install Flexisip on CentOS 6.8, how can I install hiredis-devel with version 0.11 or higher ? (because Flexisip require hiredis-devel with version 0.11 or higher, I only can install hiredis-devel with version 0.10 on CentOS 6.8)

Thanks all (sorry I am not native English speaker)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to download the file using Wget and then install it using RPM on your system to enable the EPEL repository. Use below links based on your Linux OS versions. (Make sure you must be root user).

RHEL/CentOS 7 64 Bit
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RHEL/CentOS 6 32-64 Bit
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

RHEL/CentOS 6 64-Bit ##
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm